# Efetuar calculos entre Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, vue.js, javascript-eventos

Estou utilizando um plugin que quando clica no botão de **+** ele multiplica o valor.

Ele funciona perfeitamente mas o calculo só é feito dentro do `<span id="price" class="amount"></span>` e traz o Total dentro do `<span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>`

Quando tento colocar essa interação dentro do Input ele não funciona.

```js
function calculate(obj){
                var price = parseFloat($(obj).parent().parent().parent().find('.amount').text()) || 0;
                var quantity = parseInt($(obj).parent().find('.qty').val());
                var total = price * quantity;
               
               $(obj).parent().parent().parent().find('.total_amount').text(total);
            }
    
            function changeQuantity(num,obj){
         
                $(obj).parent().find('.qty').val( parseInt($(obj).parent().find('.qty').val())+num);
            }
    
            $().ready(function(){
                //calculate();
                $(".minus").click(function(){
                    changeQuantity(-1,this);
                    calculate(this);
                });
                $(".plus").click(function(){
                    changeQuantity(1,this);
                    calculate(this);
                });
    
               
       $(".qty").keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 38)   changeQuantity(1,this);
                    if (e.keyCode == 40) changeQuantity(-1,this);
                    calculate(this);
                });
    
    
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table cart">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="cart-product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
       <th class="cart-product-name">Produto</th>
       <th class="cart-product-quantity">Quantidade</th>
       <th class="cart-product-price">Precço Unitario</th>
       <th class="cart-product-subtotal">Total</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr class="cart_item">
       <td class="cart-product-thumbnail"></td>
       <td class="cart-product-name">
         <a href="#">Pera</a>
       </td>
       <td class="cart-product-quantity">
          <div class="quantity clearfix">
             <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
              <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
               <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
           </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cart-product-price">
          R$ <span id="price" class="amount">50000</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
           <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
        </td>
        </tr>
           <tr class="cart_item">
              <td class="cart-product-thumbnail"></td>
              <td class="cart-product-name">
                 <a href="#">Uva</a>
              </td>
              <td class="cart-product-quantity">
                 <div class="quantity clearfix">
                     <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
                     <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
                      <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td class="cart-product-price">
                   R$ <span id="price" class="amount">40000</span>
                </td>
      
                <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
                   <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
                 </td>
             </tr>
              <tr class="cart_item">
                 <td class="cart-product-thumbnail"></td>
      
                <td class="cart-product-name">
                  <a href="#">Teste 3</a>
                </td>
      
       
      
                      <td class="cart-product-quantity">
                          <div class="quantity clearfix">
                              <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
                              <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
                              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="cart-product-price">
                          R$ <span id="price" class="amount">35000</span>
                      </td>
      
                      <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
                          <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
                      </td>
      
                      
                  </tr>
                  
      
                               <tr class="cart_item">
      
      
                      <td class="cart-product-thumbnail">
      
                      </td>
      
                      <td class="cart-product-name">
                          <a href="#">Teste 4</a>
                      </td>
      
       
      
                      <td class="cart-product-quantity">
                          <div class="quantity clearfix">
                              <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
                              <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
                              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="cart-product-price">
                          R$ <span id="price" class="amount">35600</span>
                      </td>
      
                      <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
                          <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
                      </td>
      
                      
                  </tr>
           </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Como assim? Qual input? Tem como você colocar a estrutura que você quer no JSFiddle, e mostrar onde tu quer que a interação funcione?

Comment: @JuniorNunes eu criei mais um Campo Input só pra mostrar como gostaria a interação

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/felipefranco/fo5bzfpc/1/

Comment: você quer que, ao mudar o valor do `input` de quantidade atualize o valor total?

Comment: Isso mesmo gostaria que alterasse o valor do total mas nao estou conseguindo fazer isso

Comment: modifiquei só o calculate, vê se é isso que você quer: https://jsfiddle.net/fo5bzfpc/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você lê os dados no interior de um `<span></span>`, você acessa o texto que está no interior das tags através do método `.text()`. Mas para ler os dados que estão em um `<input></input>`, você deve ler o seu valor, com o método `.val()`.

Assim, se você substituir estas linhas no método `calculate`:

```
var price = parseFloat($(obj).parent().parent().parent().find('.amount').text()) || 0;
/* ... */
$(obj).parent().parent().parent().find('.total_amount').text(total);
```

por estas:

```
var price = parseFloat($(obj).closest('.cart_item').find('.amount').val()) || 0;
/* ... */    
$(obj).closest('.cart_item').find('.total_amount').val(total);
```

irá ter o mesmo comportamento dos `spans`.

Além disto, alterei sua cadeia de `parent()` para o método [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), que localiza o parent mais "próximo" com aquele selector fornecido.

Fiddle aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/qvaf5bkj/1/

Por fim, a título de sugestão, você tem diversos `id's` de elementos repetidos (`quantity`, `price`, `total`) . Você deve ter apenas um `id` único para cada elemento. Mas pode ser que seja apenas para teste, já que você não os usa.

**EDITADO**

Como bem sugerido pelo @JuniorNunes, se você quiser manter os dois "sistemas", você pode modificar seu método `calculate` e checar se o elemento é um `input` através do método [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) do `jQuery`. Algo assim:

```
function calculate(obj) {

    var obj_price = $(obj).closest('.cart_item').find('.amount');
    var obj_total = $(obj).closest('.cart_item').find('.total_amount');

    var price = parseFloat( (obj_price.is("input") ? obj_price.val() : obj_price.text()) ) || 0;
    var quantity = parseInt($(obj).closest('.cart_item').find('.qty').val());
    var total = price * quantity;

    if (obj_price.is("input")) {
        obj_total.val(total);
    } else {
        obj_total.text(total);
    }
}
```

Fiddle aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/qvaf5bkj/2/

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi ele vai precisar dos 2 funcionando, esse seu jeito funciona. mas seria legal se você colocasse uma condição para checar se é um `input` ou um `span` para fazer a lógica certa. +1

Comment: Era isso mesmo @mrlew o Span nao seria necessario os IDs repetidos era apenas para teste eu vou trazer os IDs do BD

Answer (score -1):

Não vou me atentar exclusivamente para a qualidade do seu código, vou direto responder a sua dúvida sobre o `evento` do input.

Da mesma forma como você tem um tratamento para quando clicarem na "seta para cima" e "seta para baixo" dentro do `input`, basta adicionar um evento `input` no elemento para atingir o que você quer.

```js
function calculate(obj){
                var price = parseFloat($(obj).parent().parent().parent().find('.amount').text()) || 0;
                var quantity = parseInt($(obj).parent().find('.qty').val());
                var total = price * quantity;
               $(obj).parent().parent().parent().find('.total_amount').text(isNaN(total) ? 0 : total); //adicionei somente uma validação aqui de NaN
            }
    
            function changeQuantity(num,obj){
         
                $(obj).parent().find('.qty').val( parseInt($(obj).parent().find('.qty').val())+num);
            }
    
            $().ready(function(){
                //calculate();
                $(".minus").click(function(){
                    changeQuantity(-1,this);
                    calculate(this);
                });
                $(".plus").click(function(){
                    changeQuantity(1,this);
                    calculate(this);
                });
    
               
       $(".qty").keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 38)   changeQuantity(1,this);
                    if (e.keyCode == 40) changeQuantity(-1,this);
                    calculate(this);
                });
    
               
       $(".qty").on("input", function(e){
                    calculate(this);
                });
    
    
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table cart">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="cart-product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
       <th class="cart-product-name">Produto</th>
       <th class="cart-product-quantity">Quantidade</th>
       <th class="cart-product-price">Precço Unitario</th>
       <th class="cart-product-subtotal">Total</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr class="cart_item">
       <td class="cart-product-thumbnail"></td>
       <td class="cart-product-name">
         <a href="#">Pera</a>
       </td>
       <td class="cart-product-quantity">
          <div class="quantity clearfix">
             <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
              <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
               <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
           </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cart-product-price">
          R$ <span id="price" class="amount">50000</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
           <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
        </td>
        </tr>
           <tr class="cart_item">
              <td class="cart-product-thumbnail"></td>
              <td class="cart-product-name">
                 <a href="#">Uva</a>
              </td>
              <td class="cart-product-quantity">
                 <div class="quantity clearfix">
                     <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
                     <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
                      <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td class="cart-product-price">
                   R$ <span id="price" class="amount">40000</span>
                </td>
      
                <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
                   <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
                 </td>
             </tr>
              <tr class="cart_item">
                 <td class="cart-product-thumbnail"></td>
      
                <td class="cart-product-name">
                  <a href="#">Teste 3</a>
                </td>
      
       
      
                      <td class="cart-product-quantity">
                          <div class="quantity clearfix">
                              <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
                              <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
                              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="cart-product-price">
                          R$ <span id="price" class="amount">35000</span>
                      </td>
      
                      <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
                          <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
                      </td>
      
                      
                  </tr>
                  
      
                               <tr class="cart_item">
      
      
                      <td class="cart-product-thumbnail">
      
                      </td>
      
                      <td class="cart-product-name">
                          <a href="#">Teste 4</a>
                      </td>
      
       
      
                      <td class="cart-product-quantity">
                          <div class="quantity clearfix">
                              <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
                              <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" />
                              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="cart-product-price">
                          R$ <span id="price" class="amount">35600</span>
                      </td>
      
                      <td class="cart-product-subtotal">
                          <span id="total" class="total_amount"></span>
                      </td>
      
                      
                  </tr>
           </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Algo de errado com a resposta? Favor indicar para que eu possa corrigir.